# How do I get from .xlsx file to workbook using apache poi eventusermodel?

Tags: apache-poi, xssf, hssf

I need to work with both xls and xlsx. I got an outofmemory error when using xssf so I changed to sxssf and while that doesn't work I would like to change my code to use eventusermodel instead of ss usermodel. Unfortunately I do not understand very well how to use event api so if someone could provide some example code to go from File file or inputstream to a workbook.

Comment: Did you try following the [examples posted on the POI website](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api)?

Comment: Yes but I need to convert to a workbook so Im not sure how to start that..even after looking at the example on the website

Comment: You can't. If you want a full workbook, buy some more memory! If you are very resource constrained, you have to read at a low level...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Event API, meaning that you need to combine SAX for reading and `SXSSFWorkbook` for writing.

This [example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java) is an Excel to CSV convertor. You should do something likewise in the endElement() method. You should create a new Row if not created and a new cell every time there is a value (name=="v"). Set the type of the cell and the new value:

```
if ("v".equals(name)) {
            if (row == null)
                row = sheet.createRow(0);
            cell = row.createCell(thisColumn);

            switch (nextDataType) {
            case BOOL:
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN);
                char first = value.charAt(0);
                thisStr = first == '0' ? "FALSE" : "TRUE";
                if (thisStr == "FALSE")
                    cell.setCellValue(false);
                else
                    cell.setCellValue(false);

            case OTHER_CELL_TYPE:
                 //.... 

            default:
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
                break;
            }
             //......More proccessing
}
```

Here you have [the apache poi SXSSF example](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf) for a better understanding of how to save it.